# DOMPDF: page_script(): Check current page content?

Tags: header, footer, dompdf

I am using dompdf to generate reports which sometimes has a front page, and sometimes has some attachments. The main content has a header and a footer, but the front page and the attachments (the last 3 to 5 pages of the pdf) should not contain header and footer. I'm placing the header and footer with a  inline php page_script(), like this:

```
<script type="text/php"> 
    if (isset($pdf) ) { 
        $pdf->page_script('
            if ( $PAGE_COUNT > 10 && $PAGE_NUM == 1) {
                //front page footer
            }else{
                //other pages' header and footer
            }
        ');
    }
</script>
```

The whole report is built by a database engine which outputs it all as a temporary html.txt-file which is then read into DOMPDF.

Now, to recognize the front page I just have to check if the **page number is = 1**. If any attachments are added (which are comprised of 1000px-height jpg images, each on their own page)

Does anyone have an idea for how to identify these "attachment"-pages and get DOMPDF to not render a header and footer on those pages? Or is there any way I could **check within the page_script()-script whether the current page contains only an image** (or perhaps an image with a specific class or identifier)?

Thanks for any help,
David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detecting the current page contents may be possible, but I'd have to research exactly what you can do at this level. An easier method would be if you could inject some inline script in your generated document. After the main content and before the attachments you could add something like `$GLOBALS['attachments'] = true;` and then add a check on the status of this variable to your conditional.

```
<script type="text/php">
if (isset($pdf) ) {
  $pdf->page_script('
    if ( $PAGE_COUNT > 10 && $PAGE_NUM == 1) {
      //front page footer
    }elseif ($GLOBALS['attachments']) {
      //attachments actions
    }else{
      //other pages' header and footer
    }
  ');
}
</script>
```

Of course, don't forget to initialize the variable to false at the top of the document.
(from https://groups.google.com/d/topic/dompdf/mDsYi8Efnhc/discussion)

Comment: Great, thanks! This was one of the possibilities i hoped for. Since removing the header will create more whitespace on top of the page, is there any way to alter the top-margin for the attachment pages? Currently, the page margins are set by body{margin: value;} in the css file.

Comment: Truth be told in this situation I might render each of the parts separately and use pdftk to join them afterwards. The page margins can be set globally or based on the @page selectors (first, left, right). What you might try is to wrap each image in a div that breaks the page. Position the image absolutely, which will give you some flexibility in positioning (you can even go negative). If you need a sample just let me know.

Comment: Actually, I've been trying to merge the PDF with other PDF's on the server with PDFmerger (http://pdfmerger.codeplex.com/), but it complains over an error with the xref table. Do you know any workarounds for this, or another merger that works with DOMPDF? PDFtk looks like a fine desktop software, but I need the merger to be automated on the server (please correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: I'm not sure what problems pdfmerger is having, I'd have to look into it further. I currently use pdftk as part of an automated process to combine multiple PDFs into a single PDF. It should work fine so long as you can get it installed on your server.

Comment: Our web hosting unfortunately does not support installing any programs on our server, which means i would need a pure-php solution for merging the PDFs. The full error message reads "FPDF error: Unable to find xref table", and while I tried to find what made it occur I found a bunch of triggers in the css. It appeared when some properties were set, but disappeared again when i changed them to "someproperty:;". Some of the properties: font-family, font-style, margin-right on body tag, margin-left on a table class, padding-right and padding-left on another class, and so forth. Is that any help?

Comment: What version of dompdf are you using? Can you try downloading the latest code from github? https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf